# Append file, not overwrite

Tags: php, curl, download

I want append file then exist, in CURL download function, not overwrite. I use this code but it doesn't work. Please help me.

```php
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

if(isset($_GET['resumedownload'])){
    if (file_exists($dir.$dirName.'/movie.flv')) {
        $targetFile = fopen($dir.$dirName.'/movie.flv', 'r');
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_INFILE, $targetFile);
    }
}

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3600);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Ubuntu; X11; Linux i686; rv:9.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0.1");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $file);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, false );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, 'progressCallback' );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);


curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILE, $targetFile );
curl_exec($curl);
fclose($curl);
```

Comment: Your file handler for CURLOPT_FILE is flagged with 'read only'. Is this intentional?

Comment: Now save the file, but still overwrite the old file, should append to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file handler for CURLOPT_FILE is flagged with 'read only'.

Try this:

```
$targetFile = fopen($dir.$dirName.'/movie.flv', 'a');
```